# Is the difference between 'significant' and 'not-significant' significant?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, generalized-linear-model

My sample includes 744 subjects, of which 175 belong to group `L == 0`, while the other 569 to group `L == 1` (please see data below).

I used GLM for a binary outcome to test for group differences in background variables -

```
summary(
  pre <- glm(L ~ g + a + m + p + e, 
                       family = binomial("logit"), 
                       data = df))
```

... yielding significant differences for 5 of them: g, a, m, p, and e).

So I modeled these 5 background variables as covariates when testing for an association between my predictor, `chr` and my outcome `rsk`, in each one of the groups (`L == 0`, `L == 1`), again using GLM for binary outcome:

```
summary(
  fit <- glm(rsk ~ chr + g + a + m + p + e, 
             family = binomial("logit"), 
             data = df[which(df$L == 0), ]))

summary(
  fit <- glm(rsk ~ chr + g + a + m + p + e, 
             family = binomial("logit"), 
             data = df[which(df$L == 1), ]))
```

The results showed that a significant association does exist for `L == 0` but not for `L == 1`.

I would appreciate your help in **how to test whether significance/non-significance can be attributed to the group condition?**. Or in other words, is it true that for subjects `L == 0`, a significant correlation is evident, while for `L == 1' it's absent.

```
structure(list(L = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), g = c(2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), a = c(38L, 36L, 33L, 34L, 44L, 38L, 
23L, 37L, 37L, 28L, 25L, 33L, 31L, 34L, 32L, 34L, 34L, 29L, 37L, 
32L, 37L, 37L, 32L, 34L, 39L, 33L, 35L, 34L, 32L, 36L, 30L, 39L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 32L, 40L, 34L, 37L, 37L, 34L, 38L, 36L, 43L, 31L, 
37L, 32L, 31L, 42L, 31L, 31L, 34L, 39L, 32L, 36L, 30L, 47L, 34L, 
32L, 34L, 37L, 35L, 38L, 35L, 34L, 31L, 39L, 34L, 34L, 33L, 44L, 
35L, 33L, 34L, 31L, 37L, 35L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 34L, 32L, 33L, 36L, 
33L, 34L, 40L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 31L, 35L, 28L, 33L, 36L, 35L, 38L, 
34L, 36L, 33L, 32L, 37L, 31L, 32L, 35L, 30L, 33L, 31L, 35L, 38L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 39L, 32L, 33L, 36L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 
37L, 29L, 36L, 39L, 29L, 34L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 39L, 34L, 36L, 44L, 
34L, 33L, 33L, 31L, 38L, 43L, 38L, 39L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 32L, 33L, 
37L, 32L, 35L, 34L, 29L, 33L, 39L, 35L, 43L, 37L, 32L, 35L, 37L, 
39L, 31L, 37L, 31L, 34L, 35L, 39L, 33L, 34L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 36L, 
37L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 39L, 33L, 36L, 43L, 41L, 30L, 33L, 43L, 32L, 
40L, 48L, 32L, 37L, 32L, 38L, 34L, 38L, 37L, 33L, 32L, 42L, 37L, 
41L, 37L, 31L, 34L, 33L, 36L, 30L, 33L, 34L, 33L, 31L, 34L, 32L, 
39L, 31L, 39L, 33L, 33L, 32L, 39L, 31L, 34L, 33L, 41L, 29L, 41L, 
39L, 31L, 30L, 36L, 32L, 31L, 34L, 37L, 32L, 40L, 37L, 38L, 37L, 
33L, 32L, 34L, 33L, 32L, 32L, 34L, 33L, 33L, 38L, 34L, 38L, 33L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 42L, 36L, 32L, 36L, 39L, 33L, 36L, 30L, 36L, 35L, 
40L, 37L, 34L, 40L, 36L, 34L, 38L, 35L, 35L, 31L, 34L, 38L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 37L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 29L, 33L, 31L, 34L, 37L, 38L, 32L, 
30L, 35L, 27L, 33L, 36L, 36L, 34L, 31L, 34L, 31L, 37L, 34L, 34L, 
47L, 30L, 45L, 33L, 30L, 36L, 32L, 34L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 37L, 32L, 
25L, 35L, 40L, 32L, 33L, 38L, 31L, 30L, 43L, 30L, 41L, 32L, 33L, 
35L, 35L, 33L, 35L, 40L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 38L, 37L, 38L, 33L, 32L, 
34L, 34L, 43L, 31L, 31L, 35L, 34L, 31L, 41L, 32L, 34L, 36L, 39L, 
36L, 33L, 31L, 30L, 37L, 37L, 33L, 30L, 36L, 36L, 41L, 43L, 38L, 
44L, 32L, 30L, 35L, 34L, 31L, 43L, 49L, 32L, 40L, 40L, 42L, 46L, 
40L, 30L, 34L, 32L, 23L, 38L, 42L, 41L, 41L, 30L, 34L, 34L, 32L, 
33L, 35L, 36L, 42L, 36L, 30L, 33L, 41L, 31L, 37L, 28L, 34L, 32L, 
37L, 31L, 33L, 39L, 37L, 35L, 37L, 37L, 34L, 32L, 36L, 36L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 33L, 37L, 40L, 36L, 34L, 38L, 34L, 36L, 45L, 32L, 38L, 
36L, 38L, 40L, 46L, 38L, 34L, 40L, 43L, 38L, 35L, 39L, 29L, 41L, 
37L, 38L, 33L, 40L, 40L, 36L, 40L, 39L, 38L, 31L, 36L, 36L, 32L, 
34L, 39L, 49L, 46L, 33L, 42L, 33L, 58L, 28L, 30L, 35L, 35L, 32L, 
38L, 41L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 38L, 41L, 33L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 30L, 
31L, 33L, 31L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 32L, 37L, 43L, 43L, 26L, 35L, 30L, 
34L, 38L, 31L, 31L, 30L, 35L, 46L, 33L, 37L, 33L, 47L, 34L, 31L, 
35L, 30L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 37L, 40L, 32L, 29L, 27L, 40L, 36L, 41L, 
38L, 43L, 35L, 30L, 38L, 35L, 38L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 31L, 34L, 33L, 
36L, 38L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 38L, 32L, 40L, 41L, 32L, 38L, 31L, 34L, 
35L, 35L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 38L, 34L, 35L, 33L, 37L, 36L, 33L, 31L, 
31L, 33L, 34L, 41L, 47L, 35L, 35L, 43L, 37L, 35L, 34L, 32L, 41L, 
34L, 29L, 21L, 28L, 32L, 35L, 33L, 39L, 39L, 36L, 22L, 31L, 41L, 
38L, 37L, 39L, 36L, 29L, 34L, 33L, 33L, 31L, 24L, 35L, 40L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 33L, 41L, 34L, 36L, 38L, 35L, 30L, 43L, 31L, 32L, 38L, 
30L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 35L, 48L, 33L, 39L, 33L, 38L, 34L, 27L, 33L, 
34L, 32L, 33L, 39L, 35L, 43L, 40L, 34L, 39L, 33L, 35L, 42L, 36L, 
37L, 37L, 44L, 36L, 38L, 34L, 32L, 41L, 46L, 39L, 35L, 34L, 36L, 
32L, 37L, 33L, 44L, 42L, 44L, 40L, 34L, 44L, 32L, 38L, 37L, 38L, 
32L, 43L, 36L, 29L, 35L, 36L, 31L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 45L, 45L, 41L, 
28L, 38L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 38L, 33L, 36L, 44L, 43L, 
36L, 38L, 31L, 31L, 36L, 33L, 34L, 25L, 35L, 37L, 42L, 31L, 33L, 
33L, 30L, 37L, 37L, 34L, 46L, 32L, 34L, 40L, 33L, 39L, 42L, 44L, 
42L, 35L, 42L, 35L, 41L, 31L, 27L, 23L, 32L, 42L, 42L, 33L, 40L, 
38L, 29L, 40L, 33L, 33L, 43L, 40L, 41L, 32L, 31L), m = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), p = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), e = c(6L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), chr = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 1L), rsk = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 
150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 
161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 
172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 
183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 
195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 
206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 
217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 
228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 
240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 
252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 
263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 
274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 
285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 
296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 
307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 
318L, 319L, 320L, 322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 
330L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 
341L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 
352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 
364L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 
375L, 376L, 377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 
386L, 387L, 388L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 396L, 
397L, 398L, 399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 
408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 
419L, 420L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L, 
431L, 432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 441L, 
442L, 443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 451L, 452L, 
453L, 454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 
464L, 465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 474L, 
475L, 476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 
486L, 487L, 488L, 489L, 490L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 
497L, 498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 
508L, 509L, 510L, 511L, 512L, 513L, 514L, 515L, 516L, 517L, 518L, 
519L, 520L, 521L, 522L, 523L, 524L, 525L, 526L, 527L, 528L, 529L, 
530L, 531L, 532L, 533L, 534L, 535L, 536L, 537L, 538L, 539L, 540L, 
541L, 542L, 543L, 544L, 545L, 546L, 547L, 548L, 549L, 550L, 551L, 
552L, 553L, 554L, 555L, 556L, 557L, 558L, 559L, 560L, 561L, 562L, 
563L, 564L, 565L, 566L, 567L, 568L, 569L, 570L, 571L, 572L, 573L, 
574L, 575L, 576L, 577L, 578L, 579L, 580L, 581L, 582L, 583L, 585L, 
586L, 587L, 588L, 589L, 590L, 591L, 592L, 593L, 594L, 595L, 596L, 
597L, 598L, 599L, 600L, 601L, 602L, 603L, 604L, 605L, 606L, 607L, 
608L, 609L, 610L, 611L, 612L, 613L, 614L, 615L, 616L, 617L, 618L, 
619L, 620L, 621L, 622L, 623L, 624L, 625L, 626L, 627L, 628L, 629L, 
630L, 631L, 632L, 633L, 634L, 635L, 636L, 637L, 638L, 639L, 640L, 
641L, 642L, 643L, 644L, 645L, 646L, 647L, 648L, 649L, 650L, 651L, 
652L, 653L, 654L, 655L, 656L, 657L, 658L, 659L, 660L, 661L, 662L, 
663L, 664L, 665L, 666L, 667L, 668L, 669L, 670L, 671L, 672L, 673L, 
674L, 675L, 676L, 677L, 678L, 679L, 680L, 681L, 682L, 683L, 684L, 
685L, 686L, 687L, 688L, 689L, 690L, 691L, 692L, 693L, 694L, 695L, 
696L, 697L, 698L, 699L, 701L, 702L, 703L, 704L, 705L, 706L, 707L, 
708L, 709L, 710L, 711L, 712L, 713L, 714L, 715L, 716L, 717L, 718L, 
719L, 720L, 721L, 722L, 723L, 724L, 725L, 726L, 727L, 728L, 729L, 
730L, 731L, 732L, 733L, 734L, 735L, 736L, 737L, 738L, 739L, 740L, 
741L, 742L, 743L, 744L, 745L, 746L, 747L, 748L, 749L, 750L, 751L, 
752L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why not simply include `L` (and suitable interactions with the other variables) in a single model?

Comment: Thanks, whuber. I figured that a significant interaction term would tell me whether the two variables chr and rsk associate differently for different values of L (e.g., positively for L == 0 and negatively for L == 1). I am interested, however,  in knowing whether for L == 0 they are significantly associated, while for L == 1 they are not (or the opposite). Does that make sense?

Comment: If you paste your title into a search engine like duckduckgo or google (as part of your "[search and research](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)"), you should get this link: https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/000313006X152649 -- which you may find interesting. Pasting the title of that paper into a search engine should then bring up some other, related links (like discussion on Gelman's blog, and links to a preprint)

Comment: @whuber this suggestion is mathematically simple and elegant, but it will be difficult for the analyst to interpret the stratified effects without performing linear contrasts. This result will be equivalent to the fully stratified model when *all* possible interactions are included. I've worked on many problems where they truly want to stratify as a means of performing subgroup analyses. The main problem here is not having a central hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Statistical significance only makes sense for *prespecified* hypotheses. If your analysis begins by testing for significant associations among possible adjustments and the outcome for inclusion in the model, then you already have a multiple testing issue that's being ignored. A principle of regression modeling is that: **changing the number and type of adjustments to the model changes the hypothesis**. As such, the space of possible hypotheses you generate by testing 5 covariates is $2^5$!

In general, overadjustment attenuates the power of a logistic analysis. So even if all 5 covariates are truly prognostic variables (but perhaps not confounders) the resulting analysis may be biased not just based on the number of predictors versus the sample size, but based on the overall data structure and the possibility of sparse strata. If the 5 variables are in fact confounders, then you should include them in the analysis regardless, even if a small sample correction is required, so that the desired interpretation of effect is achieved.

Then there is the added nuance of performing a subgroup analysis according to $L$. Now you have added yet another complication. Usually, subgroup analyses do not correspond to primary or secondary analyses, but rather are meant as a sensitivity analysis. They are useful to detect a specific form of interaction where the effect is "consistent with the null" in one group, and "not consistent with the null" in another group. An example might be a targeted chemotherapy that works only in particular cancers with a genetic mutation. If a potential patient has wild-type disease, the drug will do nothing and it's better that they do not take it at all. Note these analyses (as well as analyses of interactions as @whuber mentioned) can at times produce contradictory results: where one subgroup fails to reject the null but not the other, yet the test of interaction is non-significant, and *vice versa*. **The meaning of a sensitivity analysis is to generate hypotheses, not confirm them**. So, knowing very little about the problem, it would make sense not to deviate from the original hypothesis which does not depend on $L$.

Answer (score 1):

The presence or absence of "statistical significance" is a very blunt tool for examination of the potential role of the L status in your data and it is rarely useful by itself in preliminary investigations. I would say that, as the bare minimum, you should instead be looking at the actual p-values as indices of the evidence in the data.

If the association observed with L=0 is weak but nonetheless "significant" with your pre-specified threshold for significance (p<0.05? Hopefully you've been more thoughtful than that.) and the association is a little weaker with L=1 then you would end up with one being "significant" and the other not without any real support for the associations being different! That may well not be close to the case with your data, but it does point to the inappropriateness of applying the significant/not significant dichotomy to this type of analysis. If you want to compare the associations then don't look to see if there is a difference between their significant/not significant status, but test the difference between those associations directly.

You've mentioned in a comment another problem with comparing the significant/not significant status of two associations. One association might be in one direction and the other in the opposite and yet they might be both statistically significant for your chosen threshold. In fact, there will always be a threshold at which two associations will be both significant and others at which they fall on opposite sides of the arbitrary boundary between significant and not significant.

Instead of asking is there an association or not, ask how big are the associations. Have you examined a graphical display of the relevant associations? If there is an important difference it will likely be discernible by eye.